# relationship between the span of the kernel and image?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have tried to find a general relationship between the kernel of a symmetric matrix and the image but have had no luck. The idea is as follows. Assume that we have $Ker(A)=Span( v_{1},v_{2})$ letting A be a 3x3 symmetric matrix, is there a way we can find $image(A)$ ?

Comment: There is no way. For example you can show that there are maps with different images, but equal kernels

Comment: "The span of the kernel" _is_ the kernel. Just so you know.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Take some vector $v\notin\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$. Then $\operatorname{Im}(A)=\operatorname{span}\{A.v\}$. Of course, this always works, even if $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: yes but what can be said about the basis of the image, wouldnt the basis change depending on what $v$ we choose?

Comment: No, it does not. If it did, my answer would be wrong. And a basis of $\operatorname{span}\{A.v\}$ is $\{A.v\}$.

Comment: thank you but what about if we wanted to utilize the fact that the matrix is symmetrical?

Comment: Right now, I don't see how to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix. Take an arbitrary vector in the image of $M$, say $Mv$ for some $v\in \Bbb  R^n$. I claim that this is orthogonal to the kernel of $M$. Indeed, take any vector $w$ in the kernel, and consider their dot product $w^T(Mv)$. The result of this product is a $1\times1$ matrix, and therefore trivially symmetric. Using the symmetry of $M$ as well, we get:
$$
w^TMv = (w^TMv)^T = v^TM^Tw = v^TMw = v^T{\vec 0} = 0
$$
so $Mv$ and $w$ are orthogonal.

By counting dimensions and using the rank-nullity theorem, we get that the image of $M$ is not only contained in, but must be exactly equal to the orthogonal complement of the kernel of $M$.

In your particular $3\times 3$ case with nullity $2$, that means that the image is spanned by the cross product $v_1\times v_2$ (assuming $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent).